# React-native, doubled call components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have noticed some strange behavior in my test app. My components with "componentWillReceiveProps" function are double call. Should be call only once after button click but it's double in weird order. 
I have 3 components:
Test        - starting component
SetMessage  - Receive props from Test and pass to Animation component
Animation   - Receive props from SetMessage and dispaly

So after click button components and functions should be call like this:

Test->SetMessage(functions:reciveProps ->setMsg) then 
Animation(functions: reciveProps->showMsg).

But in my case is:

Test->SetMessage(function:reciveProps) then Animation(function:reciveProps->showMsg) then 
SetMessage(function: changeMsg) then
Animation(functions: reciveProps->showMsg).

I would like to know, if it is normal and fine? If not, why it happens and how to fix it?

Bellow all code and logs screen.

Index.android.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Navigator,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Test from './app/components/Test/Test';
export default class testApp extends Component {


  render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <Test/>

        </View>
    )
  }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testApp', () => testApp);
```

Test.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Button,
    View,
    Animated,
    Easing,
    Switch,
} from 'react-native';
import SetMessage from '../SetMessage/SetMessage';
export default class Test extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            sendMsg:'plus'
        }
    }
    change(){
        if(this.state.sendMsg==='plus'){
            this.setState({sendMsg:'minus'});
        }else{
            this.setState({
                sendMsg:'minus'
            });
        }

        console.log('Test com ')
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.change.bind(this)}
                    title={'Start'}
                />
                <SetMessage msg={this.state.sendMsg}/>
            </View>
        )
    }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Test', () => Test);
```

SetMessage.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Button,
    View,
    Animated,
    Easing,
    Switch,
} from 'react-native';
import Animation from '../Animation/Animation';
export default class SetMessage extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            test:'',
            sendMsg:''
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.setState({
            test:nextProps.msg
        },()=>this.setMsg());

        console.log('SetMessage F - ReciveProp'+this.state.sendMsg)
    }
    setMsg(){
        console.log('SetMessage F - Change Msg '+this.state.sendMsg);
        this.setState({
            sendMsg:this.state.test
        })
    }
    render(){

        return (
            <View>

                <Animation msg={this.state.sendMsg}/>
            </View>
        )
    }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SetMessage', () => SetMessage);
```

Animation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Animated,
    Easing,
    Switch,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Animation extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            msg:'',
            bottom: new Animated.Value(-50)
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProp){
        console.log('Animation F - reciveProp'+this.state.msg);
        this.setState({
            msg:nextProp.msg
        },()=>this.showMsg());

    }
    showMsg(){
        console.log('Animation F - showMsg '+this.state.msg);
        if(this.state.msg!='') {
            Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(  // Animate over time
                    this.state.bottom,  // The animated value to drive
                    {
                        toValue: 0,
                        duration: 500  // Animate to opacity: 1, or fully opaque
                    }),
                Animated.delay(1000),
                Animated.timing(this.state.bottom,  // The animated value to drive
                    {
                        toValue: -50,
                        duration: 500  // Animate to opacity: 1, or fully opaque
                    }),
            ]).start();
        }
    }


    render(){

        return (
            <View style={styles.mainCont}>
                <Animated.View style={{
                    height:50,
                    width:100+'%',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                    alignItems:'center',
                    justifyContent:'center',
                    position:'absolute',
                    bottom:this.state.bottom,
                }}>
                    <Text style={styles.tekst}>{this.state.msg}</Text>
                </Animated.View>


            </View>
        )
    }

}
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    mainCont:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'gray'
    },
    container:{
        height:50,
        width:100+'%',
        backgroundColor:'#000',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        position:'absolute',
        bottom:0

    }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Animation', () => Animation);
```

Log screen:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the official documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

You will notice the statement "Note that React may call this method even if the props have not changed, so make sure to compare the current and next values...". I assume that some call to render is being made on one of the parents which makes a re-render call to be called on your Animation component. Hence the componentwillreceiveprops is being called. I always use this when using the hook above:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newprops) {
  if(newprops.active === this.props.active) { return }
    //if they are different do some stuff
  }
}
```